# PHP cURL Submitting POST data, multipart/form-data mess

Tags: php, html, forms, curl

So I have a site that I am building and it will be using data in a database to fill out forms on different websites. Now I understand that this can easily be done with cURL or python however when I intercept and read the post data it is usually a huge mess. For instance on this form there is only a option for comment and rating yet contains all types of other garbage:

```
-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="StylesheetManager_TSSM"
```

-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ScriptManager_TSM"

-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET"

dnn$ctr459$viewNukeNews$ctl00$ctlViewNewsComments$lbSaveCommentsRating
-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT"

-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATE"

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
-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"

CA0B0334
-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED"

-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTVALIDATION"

tA4eGr1Xgh239z393i4iChEPuFYs10biEg4Ym9fZu0aLDt7H4yWECsFXKjtzX7fHWn9WDNOm4a+nPf+qka4hzEpBfm3zRotMOrkEzCm61aM+pbZgaqhQjMPpsDhT3t6k8NkeqaSkUIyFKbXYkpx4GTyyCk0s3UPlqFR8klie6NTAkt0qPH5cjc0GzVRmMBZ5GTbA+L4oGOCgDFpCZ7SFU+/VS+37gRU3YarzwmelKqRNYutT9MwJc5beUUxCNBm6r2Zdeb8OnQnpZR2KlNT8EP+x5+Wsj9Q738H7jX5p2rCNEqmH6mK1wAVM5Rqzo8JTFdtQ6da7PAi9uMj89Vq+LXlf/6BR9vlpEk1cozY9Ny4xdZr8xKSVUYcuJYQ=
-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$dnnSEARCH$txtSearch"

-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr459$viewNukeNews$ctl00$ctlViewNewsComments$rblRating"

3
-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr459$viewNukeNews$ctl00$ctlViewNewsComments$tbComments"

COMMENT GOES HERE
-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ScrollTop"

260
-----------------------------122061295120255
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__dnnVariable"

{"__scdoff":"1","containerid_dnn_ctr459_ModuleContent":"459","cookieid_dnn_ctr459_ModuleContent":"_Module459_Visible","min_icon_459":"/Portals/_default/Containers/Apple-Orange/min.gif","max_icon_459":"/Portals/_default/Containers/Apple-Orange/max.gif","max_text":"Maximize","min_text":"Minimize"}
-----------------------------122061295120255--
 This is not a website I would be posting to however it is a very good representation of what I'm dealing with for the kinds of sites I'll be working  with. I understand how to post using the multipart/form-data however what do I do for fields such as "__EVENTVALIDATION"?
Edit: Added code that will be used

```
function post_data($site,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
    $headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------86732602411937");
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($datapost);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($datapost);
    unset($datapost);

}
```

Comment: What code are you using to generate the request? Similarly, how are you generating this data?

Comment: The post data is being intercepted using httpfox. I will update the post to include the code i'm using. However the main concern is what I'm supposed to submit to the server for the instances of the weird hidden form data sections.

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with these types of forms before. They are a pain. What I do is:

1. cURL the page, with no POST data or anything
2. Parse the HTML to get the form elements and their current values
3. Change the values for fields that you need to set
4. Format all that into an array for POST
5. Curl the page again with that POST data.

Oh and sometimes there are fields like __EVENTTYPE that need to be set to a certain string for the event you want. To help break down what your second curl should look like, use Chrome developer tools to look at the Request nicely parsed. You can even copy it as a cURL.

Comment: Thanks dan08 I'll see if I can get it up and running!!